# Windows update: download optional updates but wait with installing

Tags: windows-update

I have a MS SQL update of 1 gb as optional update. Its a service pack update.

The problem is, its an optional update, and its over 1 GB big. When I install the update, the database will temporarily go down. I have a window in which the database is permitted to go down, but with a 1gb download, its really hard to predict when I need to start the update in order to install it in the time frame.

Is there a way to download the update so I can start it at the appropriate time?

Comment: Is there a KB for the update?

Comment: Yes there is. KB3072779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the KB number of the patch open Internet Explorer and go to the link below. Windows Update catalog will only work in IE.

http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/home.aspx

once there type in the kb number Without kb and kit enter, it will find the download and you can download it now. This is the fastest way to find and download patches from Microsoft.

[image]

Comment: Great site. This is exactly what I need. Thanks. :)

Comment: Comments like yours make us try harder.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the KB Article - I would assume that you are right and this is an SQL Service pack based purely on the file size.

If you can't install through windows update, can you download the SP and offline install it?

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff803383.aspx

The above link gives you the option to download the SQL service packs and then install them manually whenever you want to.  This will remove the wait time when you are downloading through Windows Update, will allow you to install at a time to suit you and (if you save a copy somewhere) save you the bandwidth of downloading it for every individual SQL box you have.

Remember to backup your databses first!

EDIT: Based on your comment with the KB Article (KB3072779) - the article I linked to above will direct you to the following download page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/3072779

If you go about half way down the page and select your SQL version (Express, standard etc) - it will send you to a direct download page where you can get your service pack

Comment: I had accepted this answer as it is a good answer, but the problem with this answer is that I was unsure which download I need to have, and spending quality time to download a 1gb file only to find out it wasn't the right one scared me. Moab posted an answer which takes away this problem, which is why I think its the better answer. Your answer is still very good so a +1 for it for sure.